# mongoDB aggregation: how to use value as key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi I've got some records like:

```
{_id:xxx, user:1, item:A, count: 1}
{_id:xxx, user:1, item:B, count: 3}
{_id:xxx, user:2, item:A, count: 5}
{_id:xxx, user:2, item:B, count: 2}
```

can I get the dict below by using aggregate?

```
{user:1,{A:1,B:3}, user:2,{A:5,B:2}}
```

Comment: Probably be more happy to point you in the right direction if there was at least a modicum of effort showing what you "attempted" and what did not work for you. Pretty sure your question title put into a search engine should yield a number of suitable examples to at least give you a start anyway. You really should not be posting "write my code for me" questions here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)  [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)

```
db.col.aggregate([
   {"$group" : {"_id" : "$user","data" : {"$push" : {"k" : "$item","v" : "$count"}}}},
   { "$project" : {"user" : "$_id","_id" : 0, "data" : { "$arrayToObject" : "$data" }}}

])
```

Comment: I tried, but got an error "errmsg" : "$arrayToObject requires an object keys of 'k' and 'v'. Found incorrect number of keys:3".

Comment: You can check this mongo playground.